# Spring RMI: handleRemoteConnectFailure

Tags: spring, connection, rmi

I have a RMI client/server configuration created with Spring 3.0.

When client and server run on the same machine at the url:

```
  rmi://localhost:1099/myService
```

everything is ok. When I run the client on a different machine (server run now on 192.168.1.67) and the client "points" to:

```
  rmi://192.168.1.67:1099/myService
```

I can see this error message from the client:

```
  org.spring...RmiClientInterceptor handlerRemoteConnectFailure. 
  Could not connect to Rmi Service [rmi://192.1681.67:1099/myService]
```

The server is configured in this way:

```
    <bean id="myService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
       <property name="service" ref="myService"/>
       <property name="serviceInterface" value="org.myapp.MyService"/>
       <property name="serviceName" value="myService"/>
       <property name="alwaysCreateRegistry" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myService" class="org.myapp.MyServiceImpl" />
```

and the client:

```
    RmiProxyFactoryBean rpfb = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
    rpfb.setServiceInterface(MyService.class);
    rpfb.setLookupStubOnStartup(true);
    rpfb.setRefreshStubOnConnectFailure(true);
    RMICustomClientSocketFactory socketFactory = new RMICustomClientSocketFactory();
    socketFactory.setTimeout(5000);
    rpfb.setRegistryClientSocketFactory(socketFactory);
    rpfb.setServiceUrl(getRmiUrl(address, port));
    rpfb.afterPropertiesSet();
```

I checked with a sniffer the port 1099 of the server, and when the client starts its process I can see some data "dispatched" on the server side:

```
 JRMI..K
 ...192.168.1.65..
 ..192.168.1.65....
 P....w"..........................D.M...;.t..myService
 Q....w.....e...7B+@5..s}.....5org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationHandlerpxr..java.lang.reflect.Proxy.'. ..C....L..ht.%Ljava/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler;pxpsr.-java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler...........pxr..java.rmi.server.RemoteObject.a...a3....pxpw2.
 UnicastRef..127.0.1.1..../.T~.X.....e...7B+@5...x
 R
 S
 T...e...7B+@5..
```

My question is: Why if client & server run on the same machine, everything is ok but on different machines I get this problem? and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you ping that IP address from that client?

Comment: yes ping is ok. It looks client can see server properly.

Answer (score 0):

I run the server on windows and client on linux (ubuntu) and everything was ok.
When I run the server on linux and client on windows I get the problem.

To fix it on linux just run the server with: `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.67`.